# Change columns that contain string and replace rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How could I change all columns that have `"change_"` in the column name? For these columns I want to then conditionally replace rows. Want in general code for a larger dataset

```
df         change_1   comment   change_2
             onee       number   two
             three      larger   onee
```

```
[df[col].mask(df[col]=="onee","one") for col in df.columns if 'change_' in col]
```

Expected Output:

```
df         change_1   comment   change_2
             one       number    two
             three      larger   one
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`df.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to filter out columns and then use [`df.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
In [555]: cols = df.filter(like='change_').columns

In [556]: df[cols] = df[cols].replace('onee', 'one')

In [557]: df
Out[557]: 
  change_1 comment change_2
0      one  number      two
1    three  larger      one
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [str.match](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html) to find the columns that start with `change_`, then use replace:

```
res = df.columns[df.columns.str.match('change_')]
df[res] = df[res].replace({'onee' : 'one'})
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
  change_1 comment change_2
0      one  number      two
1    three  larger      one
```